# How do you search database generated listbox items from a textbox

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to implement a search/filter function with a TextBox. The TextBox should search my ListBox which is filled via data from SQL Database.

This is what I have currently tried.

```
 private void Search_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    GetAreas();
}

private void GetAreas()
{
    using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            sqlCon.Open();
            string query_search = "SELECT * FROM tblAllPostCodes WHERE (Town LIKE @Town)";
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(query_search, sqlCon);


            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Town", "%" + Search.Text + "%");

            using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(com))
            {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                adapter.Fill(dt);
                Area.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
            }
            sqlCon.Close();
        }
}
```

This is how a get my ListBox Items to show

```
public void AreaList()
    {

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter adpt = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT DISTINCT Town from tblAllPostCodes", sqlCon);
        adpt.Fill(dt);

        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            Area.Items.Add(dr["Town"].ToString());
        }

    }
```

I have tried clearing Items but they end up being cleared on search and not filling with matching text.

Any help would be appreciated I have been working on this for a while now.

Comment: Although not exactly an answer to your question, here is a tip I wish I got sooner: Consider extracting your data to lists of data objects/models, rather than using data tables. It makes the data extraction slightly more complex, but it makes everything else a lot simpler.

Answer (score 1):

You should only have to query the database once and save the results in a collection variable:

```
private readonly List<string> _allTowns = new List<string>();
public void AreaList()
{
    _allTowns.Clear();
    using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
    using (SqlDataAdapter adpt = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT DISTINCT Town from tblAllPostCodes", sqlCon))
    {
        adpt.Fill(dt);
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            _allTowns.Add(dr["Town"].ToString());
        }
    }
    Area.ItemsSource = _allTowns;
}
```

You could then simply filter the collection of all items in your `GetAreas()` method:

```
private void GetAreas()
{
    Area.ItemsSource = _allTowns.Where(x => x.Contains(Search.Text)).ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of firing an SQL query on each textchange event you should consider to just filter your dataview like:

> ```
> DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
> dv.RowFilter = String.Format("Town like '%{0}%'", SearchText);
> Area.ItemsSource = dv;
> ```

The XAML for the Listbox should look like this:

```
<ListBox DisplayMemberPath="Town"/>
```